Git Command Not Recognized in Second Stage but Works in First Stage
I'm facing an issue with my Git setup in a CI/CD pipeline.
In the First stage, Git commands work perfectly, but they fail in the Second stage. It seems that the repository is not being pulled during the Second stage and git command is not recognized:
Starting: Set extra GIT header
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.237.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents: shell
git config --global url."https://***@dev.azure.com".insteadOf "https://orgname@dev.azure.com"
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\a\_temp\1d2f3b21-87ec-4b17-b5cd-daf159f7640b.cmd""
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Set extra GIT header

Pipline yml:

stages:
- stage: First
  displayName: First
  jobs:
  - job: First
    displayName: First
    pool: selfhostedpool
    steps:

    - script: |
        git config --global url."https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com".insteadOf  "https://orgname@dev.azure.com"
      displayName: Set extra GIT header
      env:
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)

- stage: Second
  displayName: Second
  jobs:
  - deployment: Second
    environment: dev
    displayName: Second Stage
    pool: selfhostedpool
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - script: |
              git config --global url."https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com".insteadOf "https://orgname@dev.azure.com"
            displayName: Set extra GIT header
            env:
              SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)


How can I ensure that Git is a recognized command in the Second stage, just as it is in the First stage? Do i even need to set a git header in Second stage when i set it up in First stage?

Thank you in advance for your help!

In job from kind deployment the checkout not done automatically (it's should be deployment of artifacts). So, if you still want to checkout you need explicitly add it:
steps:
- checkout: self

See here more info.
